# Creating a chart showing average medical charges by unique age

Tags: pandas-groupby, scatter

I'm working with a dataset containing anonymous medical information with the following fields:

- age (years)
- sex (male/female)
- bmi
- number of childen
- smoker (yes/no)
- region
- medical charges

I've plotted a histogram to examine the age distribution of the dataset, and a scatterplot comparing the relationship between age and medical charges for each row. What I'd like to do now is build a plot that shows the average charges for individuals in each age group. The question I'm trying to answer is "On average, what are the charges for individuals at each age?"

I hope this is enough information and context.

Here's the code for the first scatterplot (works as intended, no errors):

```
#How are age and medical costs related?
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("age")
ax.set_ylabel("medical charges")
plt.title("medical charges vs age")
plt.scatter(df.age, df.charges, alpha=0.2, color='purple')
plt.show()

#round correlation coefficient to 2 decimal places
rounded_corr = "{:.2f}".format(np.corrcoef(df.age, df.charges)[0,1])

#print  the results
print("The correlation coefficient between age and charges is " + str(rounded_corr)
       + " suggesting positive but not very strong correlation.")
```

and here's what I've been trying to do (error at bottom):

```
#How are age and medical costs related?
charges_by_age = df.charges.groupby(df.age)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("age group")
ax.set_ylabel("average medical charges")
plt.title("average medical charges vs age")
plt.scatter(df.age.unique(), charges_by_age.mean(), alpha=0.2, color='blue')
plt.show()

#round correlation coefficient to 2 decimal places
rounded_corr = "{:.2f}".format(np.corrcoef(df.age.unique, charges_by_age.mean())[0,1])

#print  the results
print("The correlation coefficient between age and average charges is " + str(rounded_corr)
+ " suggesting positive but not very strong correlation.")
```

When attempting this and similar strategies, I get the following error for the correlation coefficient calculation:
**ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 47**

Thank you, kind souls, in advance for any help and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Missing () after .unique in the following code:

#round correlation coefficient to 2 decimal places
rounded_corr = "{:.2f}".format(np.corrcoef(df.age.**unique**, charges_by_age.mean())[0,1])

The code works when corrected thus:
#round correlation coefficient to 2 decimal places
rounded_corr = "{:.2f}".format(np.corrcoef(df.age.**unique()**, charges_by_age.mean())[0,1])